# how to add foreign key to Azure SQL DB Table

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I am stumped by an *Add Constraint Foreign Key* error I am encountering.

I just created TableA with a Primary Key on PLAN_ID.  The table contains zero records.  I am attemtpting to execute:

```
alter table TableB
add constraint FK_TASK_PLAN Foreign Key (TASK_PLAN_ID)
references TableA (PLAN_ID)
```

Which keeps returning
    "Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 5.  The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_TASK_PLAN".  The conflict occurred in database "DT_Worklist", table "dbo.TableA", column 'PLAN_ID'.

This essentially seems to be telling me I cannot create an FK on the specified column.
What am I doing wrong which is preventing me from creating this Foreign Key?  Is it OK my Parent Table is empty or does it need at least one record?  What about the FK column; does it need to be Not Null or does it need to have at least 1 record?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think I figured this out...  My PARENT Table which I just created is empty while my CHILD Table which was created * populated about a week ago already has values in the FK column.  So there is no way to create the PK/FK relationship when the FK already contains values.....